# vscode can't open Python interactive, and the following error occurs

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

When using vscode, can't open Python interactive, and the following error occurs:

> Activating Python 3.7.3 64-bit to run Jupyter failed with Error:
>   Command failed: D:\software\anaconda\activate base && echo
>   'e8b39361-0157-4923-80e1-22d70d46dee6' && python
>   c:/Users/HELLO/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.11.50794/pythonFiles/printEnvVariables.py
>   'D:\software\anaconda\activate'

Answer (score 1):

This [workaround](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/3834#issuecomment-487418753) worked for me. Open `settings.json` and put the following:

```
    "terminal.integrated.env.osx": {
    "PATH": ""
}
```

Note if you have

- mac, use `terminal.integrated.env.osx`
- Linux use `terminal.integrated.env.linux`
- Windows use `terminal.integrated.env.windows`

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer on the data science features for this extension. There are currently some issue with conda activation for the entire extension. This is the best issue here for tracking our fixes on this:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/5344

To get you unblocked you can see some workaround steps in this issue here:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/8290